# Find the values in a implicit function in python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, nonlinear-optimization, newtons-method

I need to find the values of some constants of the following implicit function, given the values of the variables.

```
f(Vpanel, Ipanel) = Isc - Isat(e^((Rs * Ipanel+Vpanel)/(n * Vt))-1) - (Rs*Ipanel+Vpanel)/Rp - Ipanel
```

I want to find a way to find the values of `Rs`, `Rp`, `n`, `Isat`.
I already know the approximate values, but the method I used was by brute force, so it is not an optimal way to do it.

It is an equation of the voltage X current of a solar panel and I need to find these values to calculate the maximum power transference of the panel.
The values of the variables were already measured.

I was trying to do it with `scipy` but had no success.
Here's my code:

```
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

q = 1.9*pow(10, -19)
k = 1.38*pow(10, -23)
T = 303
Isc = 0.00298
Vt = k*T/q

Vpanel = [0,0.218, 0.421, 0.635, 0.856, 1.064, 1.288, 1.477, 1.650, 1.780, 1.821, 1.846, 1.867, 1.893, 1.901, 1.922, 1.927, 1.952, 1.966, 1.973, 1.981, 1.985, 1.994, 1.997, 2.008]
Ipanel = [0.0030, 0.0030, 0.0030, 0.0030, 0.0029, 0.0029, 0.0028, 0.0028, 0.0025, 0.0021, 0.0019, 0.0017, 0.0015, 0.0013, 0.0012, 0.0010, 0.0009, 0.0007, 0.0005, 0.0005, 0.0003, 0.0003, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0]

initial_guess = [60, 1000, 1, pow(10,-20)]

for i in range(len(Vpanel)):
    def f(params):
        Rs, Rp, n, Isat = params 
        return Isc - Isat*(np.exp((Rs*Ipanel[i]+Vpanel[i])/(n*Vt))-1) - (Rs*Ipanel[i] + Vpanel[i])/Rp - Ipanel[i] 
    root = optimize.newton(f, initial_guess)
    print(root)
```

The results should be(approximately): `Rs = 68.33`, `Rp = 8000`, `n = 1.9167`, `Isat = 1E-20`.

But every time I run the code, the results are the values of the initial guesses.

I don't know if the method is the correct one, but every other method of the `scipy` library doesn't work so newton's one is the only one that gives any result.

Another thing is that I am using a **for** because I don't know how to pass the `Vpanel` and `Ipanel` lists as arguments to newton's method.

Sorry for the bad English, it's not my first language. Also is my first StackOverflow question, so I don't really know if I made the question correctly.

Comment: Why do you have a function repeatedly being defined inside a `for` loop?

Comment: BTW, you can use scientific notation in Python, e.g., `1e-20`.

Comment: In your `for` loop you seem to be trying to use `optimize` on a fixed function. You keep calling `optimize.newton(f, initial_guess)`, but I don't see anywhere `initial_guess` is every iterated on. I'm not familiar with that function, but it seems like you should actually be using `root` as your next "guess"...

Comment: Looking at `scipy.optimize.newton()`, that function only finds the root of a single-variable function. Can you clarify, are you trying to estimate the values of the two constants in your function? Or both variables and both constants?

Comment: I am trying to estimate the values of **Rs , Rp, n** and **Isat** by using the values of **Vpanel** and **Ipanel** as inputs.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how the function you defined at the top of your post is considered an implicit function. Alas, you'll probably have better luck on the [math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm gonna look through it.